Reindexing and filling missing time series values in a multi-indexed Pandas DataFrame as zero while retaining original values
My question is similar to this one : Filling in date gaps in MultiIndex Pandas Dataframe.
I however want to group by A and B and then use a user defined range to re-index and each of these dates need to be there in the index. So in this case I want to re-index from May 15th 2024 to Aug 5th 2024 in daily intervals and each combination of column A and column b should have all these dates. The dates where there is no value should be zero.
Column data type for Column  A and Column B is string and Value us int.
Table 1:



Column_A
Column_B
date
Value




a
a
6/11/2024
22


a
a
7/2/2024
35


a
a
7/9/2024
14


a
a
7/30/2024
9


a
a
7/31/2024
4


a
a
08/04/2024
40


a
a
08/05/2024
18


a
b
7/9/2024
4


a
b
8/6/2024
2


a
b
9/3/2024
5


a
c
7/9/2024
1


a
c
8/3/2024
2


b
a
8/5/2024
3



Table 2: reindexed example for where Column A=a and column B =b



Column_A
Column_B
date
Value




a
a
5/30/2024
0


a
a
5/31/2024
0


a
a
6/1/2024
0


a
a
6/2/2024
0


a
a
6/3/2024
0


a
a
6/4/2024
0


a
a
6/5/2024
0


a
a
6/6/2024
0


a
a
6/7/2024
0


a
a
6/8/2024
0


a
a
6/9/2024
0


a
a
6/10/2024
0


a
a
6/11/2024
22


a
a
6/12/2024
0


a
a
6/13/2024
0


a
a
6/14/2024
0


a
a
6/15/2024
0


a
a
6/16/2024
0


a
a
6/17/2024
0


a
a
6/18/2024
0


a
a
6/19/2024
0


a
a
6/20/2024
0


a
a
6/21/2024
0


a
a
6/22/2024
0


a
a
6/23/2024
0


a
a
6/24/2024
0


a
a
6/25/2024
0


a
a
6/26/2024
0


a
a
6/27/2024
0


a
a
6/28/2024
0


a
a
6/29/2024
0


a
a
6/30/2024
0


a
a
7/1/2024
0


a
a
7/2/2024
35


a
a
7/3/2024
0


a
a
7/4/2024
0


a
a
7/5/2024
0


a
a
7/6/2024
0


a
a
7/7/2024
0


a
a
7/8/2024
0


a
a
7/9/2024
14


a
a
7/10/2024
0


a
a
7/11/2024
0


a
a
7/12/2024
0


a
a
7/13/2024
0


a
a
7/14/2024
0


a
a
7/15/2024
0


a
a
7/16/2024
0


a
a
7/17/2024
0


a
a
7/18/2024
0


a
a
7/19/2024
0


a
a
7/20/2024
0


a
a
7/21/2024
0


a
a
7/22/2024
0


a
a
7/23/2024
0


a
a
7/24/2024
0


a
a
7/25/2024
0


a
a
7/26/2024
0


a
a
7/27/2024
0


a
a
7/28/2024
0


a
a
7/29/2024
0


a
a
7/30/2024
9


a
a
7/31/2024
4


a
a
8/1/2024
0


a
a
8/2/2024
0


a
a
8/3/2024
0


a
a
8/4/2024
40


a
a
8/5/2024
18



Based on the post I tried:
date_now = datetime.now().date() 
date_period = date_now-timedelta(days=67) 
idx = pd.date_range(date_period, date_now)
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(list(idx))--> this gives me an error
"Input must be list-like"
Could some one please help? Thanks in advance

Code
Your Column_A and Column_B are columns, not indexes, so I don't think you need to use reindex. Create a Cartesian product (merge with join='cross' )
start, end = '2024-05-15', '2024-08-05'
tmp = pd.date_range(start, end).to_frame(name='date')

out = (
    df[['Column_A', 'Column_B']]
    .drop_duplicates()
    .merge(tmp, how='cross')
    .merge(df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])), how='left')
    .assign(Value=lambda x: x['Value'].fillna(0))
)

out
    Column_A Column_B       date  Value
0          a        a 2024-05-15    0.0
1          a        a 2024-05-16    0.0
2          a        a 2024-05-17    0.0
..       ...      ...        ...    ...
329        b        a 2024-08-03    0.0
330        b        a 2024-08-04    0.0
331        b        a 2024-08-05    3.0

[332 rows x 4 columns]

example code
import pandas as pd
data = {'Column_A': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'], 'Column_B': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a'], 'date': ['6/11/2024', '7/2/2024', '7/9/2024', '7/30/2024', '7/31/2024', '08/04/2024', '08/05/2024', '7/9/2024', '8/6/2024', '9/3/2024', '7/9/2024', '8/3/2024', '8/5/2024'], 'Value': [22, 35, 14, 9, 4, 40, 18, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


This works - thank you so much for your help
